# Script that runs commands inside git bash - batch-file

Tags: batch-file, git-bash

I have a script that opens 2 git-bash terminals, but I also want to run 2 commands inside that script. Type of the file is .bat

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Git"
start git-bash.exe "--cd=C:\Homestead"
start git-bash.exe "--cd=C:\Users\user\Projects\first"
exit
```

I need a `vagrant up` and for the second one I need `npm run watch`. I tried to use `echo` but nothing happend.

Comment: Replace `cd` by `cd /D` and `start` by `start ""`…

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand. The code example works, but I need to add 2 more commands.